# How to draw a Frequency plot using the output?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Using below code i listed the top 10 most frequent words with its count now i need to put it in a frequency plot .

```
freq6000.sort_values(by=['Word Frequency'],ascending=False).head(10) 


           Word Frequency
data        124289
experience  59135
business    33528
work        28146
science     26864
learning    26850
analytics   21828
team        20825
analysis    20607
machine     20484
```

How to plot it in a Freq chart?

Answer (score 1):

Select column `Word Frequency` for `Series` and then use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
(freq6000.sort_values(by=['Word Frequency'],ascending=False)
         .head(10)['Word Frequency']
         .plot.bar())
```

Another solution with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
freq6000['Word Frequency'].nlargest(10).plot.bar()
```